# Pandas Mean of Repeating Measurement

Tags: python, database, pandas, mean

I performed a measurement where I changed a parameter and measured a physical quantity. I performed multiple measurements and saved the data to a pandas dataframe. The result looks something like this:

```
   parameter  measured_value
0         10            1.10
1         20            1.21
2         30            1.29
3         40            1.42
4         50            1.54
5         10            1.14
6         20            1.22
7         30            1.32
8         40            1.41
9         50            1.52
```

In that example I repeated the measurement twice and varied the parameter from 10 to 50 in steps of 10. Is there a way to to average the measured values, such that I get the following result:

```
   parameter  mean_measured_value
0         10            1.10
1         20            1.20
2         30            1.30
3         40            1.40
4         50            1.50
```

I analyze my data typically with matlab. Basically, I could use numpy to do data analysis like matlab, but this looks quiet unelegant:

```
meas_value = np.asarray(df['measured_value'])
mean_meas_value = np.mean(np.reshape(meas_value, (5,2)), axis=1)
```

Is there an elegant way with pandas?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about groupby. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right:

```
meas_value = df.groupby('parameter').sum()
```